# RC Filter vs Bypass Capacitor to Ground

Tags: capacitor, passive-filter

I am confused with how to implement a method of filtering out the impedance from the ground path of an IC. I'm thinking that I should use an RC filter circuit in order to smooth out the current and lower noise, but from what I've found online ([here](https://www.elprocus.com/bypass-capacitor-its-functions-and-applications/#:%7E:text=The%20bypass%20capacitor%20is%20a,cleaner%20and%20pure%20DC%20signal.)), a bypass capacitor would function similarly and is specifically designed for shorting to ground. Which one is better in this scenario? Are they both the same thing?

Comment: Do you really mean "filtering out the impedance from the ground path of an IC"?  You almost always want the ground pin/path of an IC to have as low an impedance as possible, ideally 0 ohms across the frequency band of concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am confused with how to implement a method of filtering out the
> impedance from the ground path of an IC*

Ground path impedance is a problem that is conventionally solved by using a ground plane on a circuit board. This minimizes the impedance between grounds as much as is feasibly possible on a PCB. This works up to several GHz beyond which other problems can occur but given that most applications are below 1 GHz, a ground plane is the turn to solution.

> *I'm thinking that I should use an RC filter circuit in order to smooth
> out the current and lower noise*

No, that sounds like a disaster because it would put resistance in series with the ground feed and any current noise would become a problematic voltage noise.

Adding decoupling capacitor on all chips to a ground plane is also very sensible.